# truffle exec scripts/seed-exchange.js --network kovan

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, kovan, migration

I've been running into an error when I attempt to seed my exchange/contracts on the kovan test network. Any help would be appreciated.

````
Using network 'kovan'.

Token fetched 0x69e0a4354aa5c2Ba68D4DF44D05f91BaEB3701Ed
Exchange fetched 0x700Be86E624f370202169C4F352db5Bf8464d7E8
{ Error: invalid address (arg="_to", coderType="address", value=undefined)
    at Object.throwError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3-eth-abi/~/ethers/utils/errors.js:68:1)
    at CoderAddress.encode (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3-eth-abi/~/ethers/utils/abi-coder.js:467:1)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3-eth-abi/~/ethers/utils/abi-coder.js:605:21
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at pack (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3-eth-abi/~/ethers/utils/abi-coder.js:604:1)
    at CoderTuple.encode (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3-eth-abi/~/ethers/utils/abi-coder.js:764:1)
    at AbiCoder.encode (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3-eth-abi/~/ethers/utils/abi-coder.js:897:1)
    at ABICoder.encodeParameters (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3-eth-abi/src/index.js:96:1)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3-eth-contract/src/index.js:426:1
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object._encodeMethodABI (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3-eth-contract/src/index.js:425:10)
    at constructor.detectNetwork.then.network (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-contract/lib/execute.js:170:1)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:118:7)
  reason: 'invalid address',
  code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
  arg: '_to',
  coderType: 'address',
  value: undefined }```
````

Comment: did you get this fixed? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found that by using `console.log(accounts)` in `seed-exhcange.js` only one account was making it to this point.

So I checked `truffle-config.js` with some console.log() throughout.

I found that I had put a space after the comma between my `PRIVATE_KEYS` in the `.env` file.

After removing that space everything worked great.